# Query to show each day data when we have records for 2 distinct dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Table as below:

| DEVICE ID | STATUS | Created Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Device 1 | ACTIVE | 1/10/2022 |
| Device 1 | INACTIVE | 5/10/2022 |

Now I need to write a query to show the status of every day. My Output should be as below:

- Device 1 - 1/10/2022 - ACTIVE
- Device 1 - 2/10/2022 - ACTIVE
- Device 1 - 3/10/2022 - ACTIVE
- Device 1 - 4/10/2022 - ACTIVE
- Device 1 - 5/10/2022 - INACTIVE

I have tried few queries which does not giving me correct result. So, it would be appreciate if I can get some help on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a recursive CTE as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT DEVICE_ID, STATUS, Created_Date
    FROM table_name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.DEVICE_ID, C.STATUS, DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.Created_Date)
    FROM CTE C  
    WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.Created_Date) NOT IN (SELECT Created_Date FROM table_name T WHERE T.DEVICE_ID=C.DEVICE_ID AND T.STATUS='INACTIVE')
           AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, C.Created_Date)<=GETDATE()
           AND STATUS='ACTIVE'
  )
SELECT DEVICE_ID, STATUS, Created_Date
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DEVICE_ID, Created_Date
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nbPckcpp) with extended data sample.

Comment: Assumes progression is always from Active to Inactive, and never the other way around. (Which may be true, but is currently just an assumption.)

Comment: @MatBailie, yes that is right

Comment: @MatBailie, A device may be inactive then became active, but I don't know if the OP wants to list the inactive days also, I will wait for his response to the answer. Thank you for raising this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table with every day as a record.
2. Take the following Device Status dates from *YourStatusTable* with a self join and rank them with a row_number
3. Join your status table to the date seed where the rn = 1

```
with YourStatusTable as ( 
    select 'Device 1' [Device ID],  'ACTIVE' [Status],  cast('01-Oct-2022' as date) [Created Date]
    union all select 'Device 1' [Device ID], 'INACTIVE' [Status], '05-Oct-2022' 
    union all select 'Device 1' [Device ID], 'ACTIVE' [Status], '08-Oct-2022'  
    union all select 'Device 1' [Device ID], 'INACTIVE' [Status], '12-Oct-2022' 
    union all select 'Device 2' [Device ID], 'ACTIVE' [Status], '20-Oct-2022' 
    union all select 'Device 2' [Device ID], 'INACTIVE' [Status], '25-Oct-2022' 
),

seed as ( 
    select null as n 
    union all select null
),

dates as (
    select dateadd(day,row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY a.n )-1, '-Sep-2022') date_value
    from seed a,
    seed b,
    seed c,
    seed d,
    seed e,
    seed f
),

status_boundaries as ( 
    select 
        a.[Device ID], 
        a.[Status],
        a.[Created Date],
        b.[Created Date] [next_status_date],
        row_number() over ( partition by a.[Device ID],a.[Created Date] order by b.[Created Date]) rn
    from YourStatusTable a
    left join YourStatusTable b on a.[Device ID] = b.[Device ID] and a.[Created Date] < b.[Created Date]
)

select * 
from dates
inner join status_boundaries on  date_value >= [Created Date] 
where ( date_value < next_status_date or next_status_date is null )
and rn = 1
```

Comment: Manual suggests that lead was introduced in 2012, so this doesn't work for 2008 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I've updated the answer to use a self join instead

Comment: That only works where there are two or fewer rows. If there are several rows, the left join will match on All following rows. (1 joins on 2&3&4, 2 joins on 3&4, 3 joins on 4, 4 joins on nothing)